# "ls -l" shows some abnormal files with "?"

Tags: linux, filesystems

Recently I ran into a problem with FTP server access. The server system logs shows that /etc/wu-ftpd/ftpaccess file is missing, as below:

wu-ftpd[15695]: cannot open access file /etc/wu-ftpd/ftpaccess: No such file or directory

After listing the contents of /etc/, I found serverl files were abnormal and the output contains several "?", and there is no /etc/wu-ftpd/ at all:

?---------  ? ?    ?           ?            ? inputrc

?---------  ? ?    ?           ?            ? nsswitch.conf.nis

?---------  ? ?    ?           ?            ? pam.conf

?---------  ? ?    ?           ?            ? syslog/ng

?---------  ? ?    ?           ?            ? wu/ftpd

Is there any possible reason to cause such abnormal things, like disk problem, file system crash, or inadvertent human operation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that would be a better fit for severfault or unix & linux stack exchange

Comment: There are many possible things that could have caused that but, unless the one you're interested in is what's wrong with the ***program*** you wrote that caused it, this isn't a suitable question for this site :-)

Comment: Oops.. Sorry for any inconvenience. I will try on other sites. Thanks!

Comment: That seems .. odd. If that is the standard `ls` on a local filesystem it is telling you something (that is *not* caused by userspace) is messed up very bad.